# Using xmlhttprequest response as function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve a js file which contains a function. I want to be able to store it, and call it within my page when i click a button. I included my test code.I got the response working; I was able to test it by changing the div to dusplay the text within the file.

Is it possible to store the JS functions somehow? I want to be able to add another button to this page that would trigger a function stored on the external file (alert.js).

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadJS() {
                var ajax;
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

                ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (ajax.readyState==4 )
                    {
                        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
                    }
                }
                ajax.open("GET","scripts/alerts.js",true);
                ajax.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="loadJS()">Change Content</button>
        <div id="myDiv">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your getting JavaScript from AJAX, run it through `eval()` to process it. Any function declarations in the JS can then be used by other buttons etc.

Comment: so would my js file that im "importing" neeed to be in a particular format. should it have script tags? or just the function?

Comment: Just plain JavaScript, as if you were including it with a "normal" `<script src="scripts/alerts.js`></script>` - although to be honest I don't know why you don't just use that script tag...